# Mallet Trained Model Load

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, mallet

Has anyone had any luck with loading a previously trained Model? Looking through its [API](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/), the CRFWriter class is 1/2 of the puzzle, but how exactly do you CRFRead(class doesn't exist)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the trainer that you used, you should be able to cast the object to a `CRF` or `ACRF`.  I just posted a question that might help you too: [How do I load and use a CRF trained with Mallet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522424/how-do-i-load-and-use-a-crf-trained-with-mallet)